# Utilizing a dataclass and enum together

Tags: python-3.x, enums, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to write a class that contains both behavior and static instances of the objects it defines, in doing this I'm attempting to use `dataclass(frozen=True)` and `enum`.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo(Enum):
    a: int
    b: float

    FOO1 = Foo(1, 1.0)
    FOO2 = Foo(2, 0.5)
```

An obvious complication of this approach is that you cannot define a class level variable in terms of the class itself, so I'm forced to utilize something like this:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class _Foo:
    a: int
    b: float


class Foo(Enum):
    FOO1 = _Foo(1, 1.0)
    FOO2 = _Foo(2, 0.5)
```

Doing this however causes issues with type hinting as the code thinks that `FOO1` and `FOO2` are instances of `Foos` rather than `Foo`. So okay, that could be a simple fix, so then I go with:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class _Foo:
    a: int
    b: float


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo(_Foo, Enum):
    FOO1 = _Foo(1, 1.0)
    FOO2 = _Foo(2, 0.5)
```

This now causes the program to error with `TypeError: _value_ not set in __new__, unable to create it`, and I am now at a loss. Is there a way to blend a dataclass with an enum effectively, or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: It's not clear from your example why you aren't just using an `Enum`.  You can put "behavior" via instance methods into an Enum....  Can you add some detail about what you are trying to accomplish with `Foo`?

Comment: @AirSquid dataclasses have automatic usage of `__slots__` that I desire

Comment: interesting....  I've never used `__slots__`  ...  I'm gonna do some reading.  It seems the answer below is on point and I don't think `__slots__` which would be some kind of class variable are implementable in an enum.

Comment: @user852541 that sounds like a terrible reason to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this works well with typing (please post a comment letting me know), but, as of Python3.11, `Enum` is optimized to work with `dataclass` using the following pattern:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    a: int
    b: float

class FooEnum(Foo, Enum):
    FOO1 = 1, 1.0
    FOO2 = 2, 0.5
```

and in use:

```
>>> FooEnum.FOO1
<FooEnum.FOO1: a=1, b=1.0>

>>> FooEnum.FOO1.value
Foo(a=1, b=1.0)
```